# Adding validation to knockout

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-validate, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to use jquery validation. I'm loading the list of items via ajax, load my knockout model. I would like to bind validation to those items. The problem is that the validation messages show up on the first  input box ONLY. what am i doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        viewModel.load();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        $('#list').validate();
});
```

Then in my viewModel:

```
    self.load = function (selected) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: myUrl,
            data: ko.toJSON({ type: self.url(), customerNumbers: selected }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".demo-tbl").block({ message: "Loading..." });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $(".demo-tbl").unblock();
                // COMMENTED OUT $("input.percent-text").valid(); // validator
            },
            success: function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
    };
```

Rendered HTML:

```
                           <form id="list">
                            <table class="demo-tbl" data-bind='visible: List().length > 0'>
                                <thead>
                                </thead>


<tbody data-bind="foreach: List">
    <tr class="tbl-item" data-bind="css: HasDiscount">
        <td>
            <dl>
                <dt class="like" data-bind="text: CustomerName"></dt>
                <dd>Customer Number: <span data-bind="text: CustomerNumber"></span></dd>
            </dl>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="label label-sm label-warning" data-bind="css: HasDiscount, text: $root.DiscountListType"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <dl>
                <dt class="like">Activation Date:</dt>
                <dd data-bind="text: moment(ActivationDate()).format('LLL')"></dd>
            </dl>
        </td>
        <!-- ko if: $parent.DiscountListType() == "DiscountOverwrite" -->
        <td class="action">
            <input class="required number percent-text" name="percent" data-bind="numeric: Percent, value: Percent, event: { keypress: $root.update, blur: $root.update }" type="number" min="1" max="100" oninput="maxlength(this)" maxlength="3" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <td class="checkbox-cell">
            <button class="btn action" type="button" data-bind="click: $root.action, css: HasDiscount"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

                            </table>
                        </form>
```

EDIT 1:

```
...
              complete: function () {
                    $(".demo-tbl").unblock();
                    $('#list').validate();
                },
...
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".demo-tbl").length > 0) {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        viewModel.load();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see a `<form></form>` container in your HTML.  Also please only show the ***rendered*** HTML as seen in the browser.

Comment: added rendered html. like i said i'm loading the page, getting the list via ajax. The validation works but the <error label> generated by validate plugin only gets generated for the FIRST item in the list only. So if the second row has an issue the error message shows up next to the first row instead of second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The problem is that the validation messages show up on the first input box ONLY. what am i doing wrong?"

Based on the code you've shown, jQuery Validate should not be working at all.

You can only attach the `.validate()` method to the `form`, not to an input element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#list').validate(); // initialize plugin on your form

});
```

**Note:  The `name` attribute is how the plugin keeps track of the fields, so repeating the names will result in something like you describe where some elements are skipped.  I thought I saw a `name` repeated in the first version of your HTML.**

---

You cannot attach the `.validate()` method to a `form` element that does not yet exist.  If your `ajax()` is loading the HTML for the `form`, then call `.validate()` right after the form's HTML is successfully loaded.

The same place you commented out your call to `.validate()`, except this time it's attached to the `form`, not the input element.

```
self.load = function (selected) {
    $.ajax({
        ....
        complete: function () {
            $(".demo-tbl").unblock();
            $('#list').validate(); // initialize validate plugin
        },
        ....
    });
};
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Stressing my original "note" above.  You must **NOT** repeat a `name` attribute or the plugin will fail.  There is no workaround.  You must ensure every input contains a *unique* `name`.

```
name="percent[1]"
name="percent[2]"
name="percent[3]"
....
```

Comment: I've added this to jquery document ready and still errors only show up next to the first input. Please see updated code above

Comment: @ShaneKm, see my edits.  Call `.validate()` immediately after loading the HTML.  The `form` MUST exist before you can initialize the plugin on it.

Comment: I did. pls see EDIT1. Now the validation messages show up on the second row ONLY

Comment: @ShaneKm, that is a different issue.  See the "note" in my original answer:  *"The `name` attribute is how the plugin keeps track of the fields, so repeating the names will result in something like you describe where some elements are skipped. I thought I saw a `name` repeated in the first version of your HTML."*